# JavaFx KeyPressed event consumed, still in TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, key-events

I made a simple Pong game with JavaFx. However I have a problem with setting controls. I'm using a TextField like this:

```
control_0.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
            {
                control_0.setText(ke.getCode().toString());
                om.setControls(0,ke.getCode().toString());
                ke.consume();
            }
        });
```

However, whenever a key that types a character is pressed, it duplicetes in the TextField like a so: sS.
Replacing the handle() code with

```
control_0.setText("");
om.setControls(0,ke.getCode().toString());
```

takes care of that, however arrow keys and similar show nothing in the TextField (although they do work in-game). How do I fix this problem / consistecy issue?

Answer (score -1):

You do not actually seem to need a `TextField`. You could simply replace the `TextField` with a `Label` and add the event handler to the `Scene`.

However if you do insist on using a `TextField`, you can use an event **filter** for all `KeyEvent`s to prevent the event from reaching the default `EventHandler` that modifies the text of the `TextField`:

```
control_0.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, evt -> {
    if (evt.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
        control_0.setText(evt.getCode().toString());
    }
    evt.consume();
});
```

Comment: well, I would first need to remove focus from other components of my Scene. I kinda fail to see the difference (both consume(), both setText(), only I setText() on KEY_TYPED and RELEASED as well, still should just set the text, not append)