# JavaFX KeyEvent.consume() Fails to Stop Event Propagation

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to reproduce some behavior of a JavaScript game in JavaFX. The program has several numeric text fields that can be edited as the game is running. It also accepts alphabetic keyboard commands while running.

In my version, I try to capture, react to, and remove keyboard commands even when one of the numeric text fields is focused. I thought using an `EventFilter` should work -- consuming the keyboard events before they reach the `TextField`s during the capture phase of handling the event. But so far I have not been able to stop the alphabetic keyboard input from reaching the text field.

Here is an SSCCE that illustrates what I have tried and what is not working.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class KeyFilterSSCCE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Key Filter SSCCE");
        TextField tf = new TextField("XYZ abc");
        tf.setMaxWidth(150);
        Label label = new Label("Filtered Keys: ");
        VBox root = new VBox(20, tf, label);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 325, 200);

        stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                label.setText(label.getText() + e.getCode().getChar());
                e.consume();
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The program should let you type into the text field and capture and remove 'S' characters before they are input into the field.  The code shows that the 'S' characters are detected correctly, but they still show up in the text field, even after being `consume()`ed.

After the call to `consume()`, the `isConsumed()` method confirms that the event is correctly marked as consumed, but the dispatch chain is not short-circuited as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJCICG) indicates.

I've tried adding the event filter to other `Node`s in the path down to the text field with no change in behavior. I've tried filtering `KeyEvent.ANY`, `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED`, and `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED` without and change in behavior. I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482580/javafx-keypressed-event-consumed-still-in-textfield) with an answer that proposed something like what I am trying.

Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Since all of the `TextField`s in the real program have attached `TextFormatter`s, I suppose I could add a filter function to the formatter to reject the keyboard command characters. That seems like a roundabout way of doing it though.

macOS, Java 17, JavaFX 17 if that makes any difference.

Comment: This sounds like a use-case where you should be using `TextFormatter` over `EventFilter`. I could be wrong due to my limited experience using `EventFilter` and `TextFormatter`.

Comment: Here is my train of thought when trying to figure out which one to use. If you are going to be doing anything with the text in the `TextField`, use `TextFormatter`. If you are not, use `EventFilter`. Here is a good example: https://courses.bekwam.net/public_tutorials/bkcourse_visualcueapp.html.

Comment: consume the typed in the filter

Comment: .. to clarify my nightly comment: _The code shows that the 'S' characters are detected correctly, but they still show up in the text field_ no wonder, it's inserted by a __keyTyped__ (vs. the keyPressed which you consume). The solution is to consume the keyTyped in the filter.

Comment: @kleopatra, thank you. With your help I came up with a working filter.

Answer (score 2):

After @kleopatras comment and a little more experimentation, here is a version of the event filter that operates as expected:

```
    stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, e -> {
        if (e.getCharacter().toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
            label.setText(label.getText() + e.getCharacter());
            e.consume();
        }
    });
```

Filtering for the `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` event was what I needed. In addition, since the event `getCode()` method for that event returns `UNDEFINED`, the test had to be modified a bit to test against the result for `getCharacter()`, which, oddly, returns a `String`.